# Failed to retrieve Sender Profile

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'am using A/B testing in Salesforce exact target . When I send a email using A/B testing I get an error message "Failed to retrieve Sender Profile. Please contact your system administrator." .

What does this error message mean and how can this be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error came in Salesforce because I was using an older version of marketing cloud in Salesforce . I upgraded the marketing cloud manage package in Salesforce and this was resolved .

Answer (score 0):

Have you created Sender Profile(s) to use for this A/B testing?

If not, I believe that is the problem. 
Setup Sender Profiles info here:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/#How_to_Create_a_Sender_Profile